# Properties of Sobolev spaces $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I'm looking for different properties of spaces $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$ for bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $k \geq 1$ that I couldn't find in literature. References are wery welcome.

1. *Extension.* Theorem 12.15 of Giovanni Leoni "A first course in Sobolev spaces" tells us that if $\Omega$ has Lipshitz boundary then there exists a continuous linear extension operator from $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ to $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$. What about spaces $W^{k,\infty}$ for $k \geq 2$? Does there exist a continuous extension operator in the case of $C^k$ boundary $\partial \Omega$?
2. *Trace.* Theorem 5, p. 131 of Evans "Measure theory and fine properties of functions" tells us that $f \in W^{1,\infty}_\text{loc}(\Omega)$ if and only if $f$ is locally Lipshitz in $\Omega$. If I'm not mistaken, combining this with the above extension result we obtain that for any $f \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ we can define its trace on $\partial D$ as an element of $W^{1,\infty}(\partial \Omega)$ if $\partial \Omega \in C^1$. To do this we extend $f$ to $\widetilde f \in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ so that $\widetilde f|_{\partial D}$ is the restriction of the Lipshitz function which is Lipshitz and hence $W^{1,\infty}(\partial D)$. Is it true in general that the trace operator continuously maps $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$ to $W^{k,\infty}(\partial \Omega)$ if $k \geq 1$, $\partial \Omega \in C^k$? (Intuitively it must be true since taking trace on $W^{k,p}$ "costs" 1/p smoothness).
3. *Extension from boundary.* Let $f \in W^{1,\infty}(\partial D)$. Then (as above) $f$ is Lipshitz. Then by the Kirszbraun theorem $f$ can be extended to a Lipshitz $\widetilde f$ (the extension not necessarily linear) on $\mathbb R^n$ and hence to $\widetilde f|_\Omega \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$. Does the same result hold for $f \in W^{k,\infty}(\partial D)$, $k \geq 2$?

Any comments are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Look in Chapter VI of *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions* by Elias Stein.

Comment: In particular, theorem 5 page 181 (edition of 1970) may be what you're looking for the first point of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Yes there is one. Please check [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120441438) book, section $5.17$

Q2: I don't have a reference for this but as you said, this is proved by extension...

Q3: Yes, I think we can try induction.

Comment: Unfortunately, in section 5.17 the author doesn't consider the spaces $W^{k,p}$ with $p = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:**
Chapter 6 of
Burenkov (1998) "Sobolev Spaces on Domains" ([LINK](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-663-11374-4))
has extension theorems for $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$.
(The Adams and Fournier textbook reference suggested by @spatially does not include the case $p=\infty$)

More specifically for $k\in\mathbb{N}$:

- When $\Omega$ has $C^k$ boundary see Chapter 6, Theorem 2 (pg. 270) for extensions of
  $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$ to $W^{k,\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$.
- When $\Omega$ has Lipschitz boundary Chapter 6, Theorem 3 (pg. 285) gives an even stronger result for extensions of
  $W^{k,\infty}(\Omega)$ to $W^{k,\infty}(\mathbb R^n) \bigcap C^{\infty}(^c\overline{\Omega})$.

**Q2 and Q3:** Sorry, I have not looked closely for an answer to these questions but this Burenkov (1998) textbook might have what you're looking for.
In particular, Chapter 1 Lemma 9 (pg. 34), and Chapter 5 may be of interest.